# add multiple input fields dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add my form input field dynamically by clicking the add more button.

Following is the `HTML` of the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
  <div id="filediv">
    <input name="file[]" type="file" id="file" />
  </div>
  <div id="filediv2">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="10" id="des"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="filediv3">
    <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload" />
</form>
```

I tried the following, But it doesn't append all fields when add more button is clicked. I want to add all  3 field with add more action.

```
 $('#add_more').click(function () {
   $(this).before($("<div/>", {
     id: 'filediv',
     id: 'filediv2',
     id: 'filediv3'
   }).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
     name: 'file[]',
     type: 'file',
     id: 'file'
   }), $("<br/><br/>")),

   $("<input/>", {
     name: 'des',
     type: 'textarea',
     id: 'des'
   }), $("<br/><br/>"))
);
});
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create one `<div>` with multiple `id`s?

Comment: By *"my form input field"*, did you mean the `<input>` elements alone..? or do you want to insert the `<textarea>` and `<select>` as well..? Your question is not clear which is why you're getting downvoted... Please [edit] the question and rephrase it properly... Also, Your code doesn't work at all because it contains syntax errors, which is easier to spot if you format your code properly or open the browsers console...

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the elements you want to dynamically insert in a container element, You can use jQuery [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone) method to create a copy of it and insert it before the add more button as shown below:

```js
$('#add_more').click(function () {
    $(this).before($(".template").clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    <div class="template">
        <div class="filediv">
            <input name="file[]" type="file" id="file" />
        </div>
        <div class="filediv2">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="10" id="des"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="filediv3">
            <select>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" class="upload" />
    </div>
</form>
<input type="button" id="add_more" value="Add More Files" />
```

Side Note: It is better not to use `id` in a dynamic template, If you do, you'll have to go through the pain of having to remove them...

Comment: may I ask something, how the action page for this form? I so need this form

Comment: @DickyMahardika Sorry I didn't understand your question... could you rephrase it..?